# composer not defined or environnement

Tags: php, composer-php

I tried to execute a function to update composer but composer is not defined

my composer.json is in 777 
my composer.lock is in 644

thank you

1/

```
static::$root = '/var/www/demo/shop/';

public function update() {
  putenv('COMPOSER_HOME=' . static::$root);


  $cmd = '/usr/bin/composer ' . static::$root . 'composer diagnose -vvv 2>&1';

  exec($cmd, $output, $return); // update dependencies

  $result = print_r($output,true) .  $return;

  return $result;
}
```

result :

```
Array ( [0] => Reading /home/www/demo/shop/composer.json [1] => Loading config file /home/www/demo/shop/composer.json [2] => Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid [3] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v [4] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): git describe --exact-match --tags [5] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD [6] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): hg branch [7] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): fossil branch list [8] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): fossil tag list [9] => Executing command (/home/www/demo/shop): svn info --xml [10] => Cannot create cache directory /home/www/demo/shop//cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.org/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache [11] => Cannot create cache directory /home/www/demo/shop//cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache [12] => Reading /home/www/demo/shop/includes/ClicShopping/External/vendor/composer/installed.json [13] => Running 1.8.4 (2019-02-11 10:52:10) with PHP 7.3.2-3 on Linux / 5.0.0-31-generic [14] => [15] => In Application.php line 618: [16] => [17] => [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] [18] => Command "/home/www/demo/shop/composer" is not defined. [19] => [20] => [21] => Exception trace: [22] => () at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:618 [23] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:229 [24] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:258 [25] => Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:148 [26] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:104 [27] => Composer\Console\Application->run() at /usr/bin/composer:57 [28] => ) 1
```

Include cache directory :

```
Array ( [0] => Reading /home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/composer.json [1] => Loading config file /home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/composer.json [2] => Checked CA file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt: valid [3] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): git branch --no-color --no-abbrev -v [4] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): git describe --exact-match --tags [5] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): git log --pretty="%H" -n1 HEAD [6] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): hg branch [7] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): fossil branch list [8] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): fossil tag list [9] => Executing command (/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop): svn info --xml [10] => Reading /home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/includes/ClicShopping/External/vendor/composer/installed.json [11] => Running 1.8.4 (2019-02-11 10:52:10) with PHP 7.3.2-3 on Linux / 5.0.0-31-generic [12] => [13] => In Application.php line 618: [14] => [15] => [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\CommandNotFoundException] [16] => Command "/home/www/clicshopping_test/shop/composer" is not defined. [17] => [18] => [19] => Exception trace: [20] => () at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:618 [21] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->find() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:229 [22] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:258 [23] => Composer\Console\Application->doRun() at /usr/share/php/Symfony/Component/Console/Application.php:148 [24] => Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /usr/share/php/Composer/Console/Application.php:104 [25] => Composer\Console\Application->run() at /usr/bin/composer:57 [26] => ) 1
```

Comment: I think your command just be this:  `$cmd = '/usr/bin/composer diagnose -vvv 2>&1';`

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. It working for me.

I think you should set 664 for permission on both file.

sometime 777 is not acceptable because some security reasons. At that time change permission level to 664.

Comment: I inclue the cache directory but the result is the same, see above I added the result with cache directory